# how to format the response output to xml in wso2 esb

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, cdata, wso2-esb

I have a SAP MII webservice which when i try it using soap ui gives me response as:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
       xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
       <soap:Body>
              <XacuteResponse xmlns="http://www.sap.com/xMII">
                     <Rowset>
                           <Row>
                                  <outxml><![CDATA[&lt;BAPI_PROCORD_GET_LIST&gt;
&lt;INPUT&gt;&lt;COLLECTIVE_ORDER/&gt;&lt;/INPUT&gt;
&lt;OUTPUT&gt;&lt;RETURN&gt;&lt;TYPE/&gt;&lt;ID/&gt;&lt;NUMBER&gt;000&lt;/NUMBER&gt;&lt;MESSAGE/&gt;&lt;LOG_NO/&gt;&lt;LOG_MSG_NO&gt;000000&lt;/LOG_MSG_NO&gt;&lt;MESSAGE_V1/&gt;&lt;MESSAGE_V2/&gt;&lt;MESSAGE_V3/&gt;&lt;MESSAGE_V4/&gt;&lt;PARAMETER/&gt;&lt;ROW&gt;0&lt;/ROW&gt;&lt;FIELD/&gt;&lt;SYSTEM/&gt;&lt;/RETURN&gt;&lt;/OUTPUT&gt;
&lt;TABLES&gt;&lt;MATERIAL_RANGE&gt;&lt;item&gt;&lt;SIGN&gt;I&lt;/SIGN&gt;&lt;OPTION&gt;EQ&lt;/OPTION&gt;&lt;LOW&gt;RUBBER_COMPOUND&lt;/LOW&gt;&lt;HIGH/&gt;&lt;/item&gt;&lt;/MATERIAL_RANGE&gt;&lt;MRP_CNTRL_RANGE/&gt;&lt;ORDER_HEADER&gt;&lt;item&gt;&lt;ORDER_NUMBER&gt;000070001202&lt;/ORDER_NUMBER&gt;&lt;PRODUCTION_PLANT&gt;3100&lt;/PRODUCTION_PLANT&gt;&lt;MRP_CONTROLLER/&gt;&lt;PRODUCTION_SCHEDULER/&gt;&lt;MATERIAL&gt;RUBBER_COMPOUND&lt;/MATERIAL&gt;&lt;EXPL_DATE&gt;2014-02-03&lt;/EXPL_DATE&gt;&lt;ROUTING_NO&gt;0000013579&lt;/ROUTING_NO&gt;&lt;RESERVATION_NUMBER&gt;0000069876&lt;/RESERVATION_NUMBER&gt;&lt;SCHED_RELEASE_DATE&gt;2014-02-03&lt;/SCHED_RELEASE_DATE&gt;&lt;ACTUAL_RELEASE_DATE&gt;2014-02-03&lt;/ACTUAL_RELEASE_DATE&gt;&lt;FINISH_DATE&gt;2014-02-03&lt;/FINISH_DATE&gt;&lt;START_DATE&gt;2014-02-03&lt;/START_DATE&gt;&lt;PRODUCTION_FINISH_DATE&gt;2014-02-03&lt;/PRODUCTION_FINISH_DATE&gt;&lt;PRODUCTION_START_DATE&gt;2014-02-03&lt;/PRODUCTION_START_DATE&gt;&lt;ACTUAL_START_DATE&gt;2014-02-04&lt;/ACTUAL_START_DATE&gt;&lt;ACTUAL_FINISH_DATE&gt;0000-00-00&lt;/ACTUAL_FINISH_DATE&gt;&lt;SCRAP&gt;0&lt;/SCRAP&gt;&lt;TARGET_QUANTITY&gt;100.000&lt;/TARGET_QUANTITY&gt;&lt;UNIT&gt;ST&lt;/UNIT&gt;&lt;UNIT_ISO&gt;PCE&lt;/UNIT_ISO&gt;&lt;PRIORITY/&gt;&lt;ORDER_TYPE&gt;PI01&lt;/ORDER_TYPE&gt;&lt;ENTERED_BY&gt;277458&lt;/ENTERED_BY&gt;&lt;ENTER_DATE&gt;2014-02-03&lt;/ENTER_DATE&gt;&lt;DELETION_FLAG/&gt;&lt;WBS_ELEMENT&gt;00000000&lt;/WBS_ELEMENT&gt;&lt;CONF_NO&gt;0000108111&lt;/CONF_NO&gt;&lt;CONF_CNT&gt;00000001&lt;/CONF_CNT&gt;&lt;INT_OBJ_NO&gt;000000000000000000&lt;/INT_OBJ_NO&gt;&lt;SCHED_FIN_TIME&gt;06:07:49&lt;/SCHED_FIN_TIME&gt;&lt;SCHED_START_TIME&gt;06:07:49&lt;/SCHED_START_TIME&gt;&lt;COLLECTIVE_ORDER/&gt;&lt;ORDER_SEQ_NO&gt;00000000000000&lt;/ORDER_SEQ_NO&gt;&lt;FINISH_TIME&gt;06:07:49&lt;/FINISH_TIME&gt;&lt;START_TIME&gt;06:07:49&lt;/START_TIME&gt;&lt;ACTUAL_START_TIME&gt;15:43:47&lt;/ACTUAL_START_TIME&gt;&lt;LEADING_ORDER/&gt;&lt;SALES_ORDER/&gt;&lt;SALES_ORDER_ITEM&gt;000000&lt;/SALES_ORDER_ITEM&gt;&lt;PROD_SCHED_PROFILE/&gt;&lt;MATERIAL_TEXT&gt;RubberCompound&lt;/MATERIAL_TEXT&gt;&lt;SYSTEM_STATUS&gt;TECO PCNF MACM SETC
&lt;/TABLES&gt;
&lt;/BAPI_PROCORD_GET_LIST&gt;]]></outxml>
                           </Row>
                     </Rowset>
              </XacuteResponse>
       </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The problem is when i create a pass through proxy of the webservice then upon running the service in soap ui i get garbage value from esb. I want to convert this response into well formed response xml structure. **i tried using xslt but it gives error in esb as Unable to create response structure**. The same xslt when run on eclipse is working fine. Please Help me. Thanks in advance and looking forward to your solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The XML fragment inside CDATA is not well-formed (end tags are missing).

But assuming you find a way to correct that and if the given syntax in your post is exactly what you are receiving, you can try that :

1- get the CDATA content:

```
<property name="CDATA_CONTENT" expression="$body//outxml"/>
```

2- create a new XML property with this content :

```
<script language="js">mc.setProperty("XML_CONTENT",new XML(new XML(mc.getProperty('CDATA_CONTENT'))));</script>
```

3- extract values from this XML fragment :

```
<log level="custom">
  <property name="result" expression="get-property('XML_CONTENT')"/>
  <property name="orderNumber" expression="get-property('XML_CONTENT')//ORDER_NUMBER/text()"/>
</log>
```

4- change current message payload with this XML fragment :

```
<script language="js">mc.setPayloadXML(new XML(new XML(mc.getProperty('CDATA_CONTENT'))));</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jean but when i want to log the value of property CDATA_CONTENT i dont get anything. here is the code

Comment: <outSequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <property name="CDATA_CONTENT" expression="$body//outxml"/>
   <xslt key="SapTransformation"/>
   <log level="custom">
      <property name="result" expression="get-property('CDATA_CONTENT')"/>
   </log>
   <send/>
</outSequence>

Comment: This is because of the namespace, XPATH should be something like $body//sap:outxml with xmlns:sap="h ttp://www.sap.com/xMII" (without space between h and ttp...but it disapear in this comment otherwise)

Comment: Still having the same problem. One thing more if i log the property with expression as $body i see <axis2ns5:binary xmlns:axis2ns5="_http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">Garbage Value like YQ==</axis2ns5:binary>

Comment: Not sure to understand, it seems that your response SOAP message is not the one you show in your post : try with a <log level="full"/> in outSequence

Comment: This is really strange, When i hit the original service of SAP MII on soap ui i get a proper response with CDATA that i mentioned in my question, but when i hit the pass through proxy of above service. In outsequence when i do log level full i get the above binary output.

Comment: What is the contentType of the response message (use "Row" view of response in SoapUI) ?

Comment: content-type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
content-encoding: gzip

Comment: verify if a specific messageBuilder is associated with contentType="text/xml" inside axis2 conf (repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml)

Comment: the response from the sap service is GZIPPED Response. How to Decompress it

Comment: In my mind, wso2 should decompress it but for the test, stop accepting gzip encoding with this property inside inSequence : <property name="Accept-Encoding" scope="transport" action="remove"/>

Comment: I did as you have suggested but still the same problem. When i try it with saopUI it gives me wsdl of the sap service as response

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you anymore, it seems that the problem is not in WSO2 ESB. I hope you will find a solution with your SAP service and then, hope that my initial answer will help you to deserialize the CDATA content

Comment: try uri fromat with 'pox'